# "Unable to set Transaction Id on connection" error - Spring DatasourceTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions, db2

I am in the process of migrating a legacy WebSphere application to Spring boot. This application makes heavy use of database transactions and seemed to work fine until it hits a particular block annotated with "@Transactional". The only errors it gives are "Unable to set Transaction Id on connection" and a DB2 SQL error:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: 
  DB2 SQL Error: 
    SQLCODE=-104, 
    SQLSTATE=42601, 
    SQLERRMC=<END-OF-STATEMENT>;
WITHIN <IDENTIFIER> INTO FROM OVER * AT YEAR YEARS , DRIVER=4.16.53
```

Not exactly sure where this SQL is coming from, guessing it may be something Spring or the driver uses to communicate with DB2.

The app is able to use transactions in other methods without issue.

We are currently using the latest version of the DB2 JDBC driver available at my organization, and using Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE. 
Removing `@Transactional` seems to "fix" the problem, however now it is not running as a context and we cannot count on the data integrity, so this is not a good solution to this problem.

I thought it may have been an issue with our DAO code, however, I tried commenting out all of the DAO calls in the transaction block and the same error occurs.

I saw that there is sometimes an issue when not using concrete classes in transactional blocks, so I made the abstract DAO that our other DAO's inherit from a concrete class and still no luck. I know the docs refer to interfaces in this regard, but I figured it was still worth trying.

[Source:](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#spring-data-tier>)"The Spring team recommends that you annotate only concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes) with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces..."

Adding `readOnly=true` seems to have also prevented the error from occurring, however in this particular transactional block we are doing inserts, and updates so the readOnly flag is not particularly accurate either.

Here is an example of what is going on that is failing. When debugging, the error is thrown in Spring's `TransactionInterceptor` class, so it appears to be happening before `doDatabaseStuff()` is ever actually executed.

```java
@Transactional
public void doDatabaseStuff(Stuff stuff){
     daoA.batchUpdate(stuff);
     daoB.batchInsert(stuff);
}
```

Here is an example of the "working" code with read-only:

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void doDatabaseStuff(Stuff stuff){
     //not readOnly operations
     daoA.batchUpdate(stuff);
     daoB.batchInsert(stuff);
}
```

I am expecting this code to work in the context of a transaction, and not throw the error described above.

Comment: Does the *Db2-server* run on Z/os, or i-series,  or  linux/unix/windows ?

Comment: You are using an old Db2-jdbc driver (always a bad idea to use Fixpack-0 of any driver from IBM ).  Get a recent driver from https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads

Comment: Could be related to https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/pre-process-job-fails-sqlcode-104-sqlstate42601 ?